# How to show/hide listview elements?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I'm creating a chat application. I want to show the time when user clicks on message

[image]. This feature is working with this code in getView() of BaseAdapter

```
holder.txt_msg_user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

if (holder.txt_date_user.isShown() && holder.txt_AM_user.isShown())
                    {
                        holder.usertimelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.txt_date_user.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.txt_AM_user.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        holder.usertimelayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.txt_date_user.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.txt_AM_user.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                }
            });
```

But i want to add one more feature, like in the below image if i click on every message every message is showing its time, but i want to achieve one thing like skype, if user sees the time of any message then first it will check for the previous messages. If any previous message is showing the time then it should be hide & recently tapped on message by the user should be shown.Please help how it can be possible. This is the problem: (see image)

[image]

Comment: You could keep track the selected message in a variable in the class. When the user clicks in another, it hides on the selected, shows the current, and males the current the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're achieving the time already and it's being added to each list item, perhaps you could just set the last item in your listview to View.VISIBLE and the rest to View.GONE.

Answer (score 0):

You keep a property like:

```
View selectedMessage;
```

Where you set when the user clicks in some message, and verify it:

```
...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (selectedMessage != null && v != selectedMessage) {
         Holder h = (Holder) selectedMessage.getTag();
         h.hideTime();

         h = (Holder) v.getTag();
         h.showTime();

        selectedMessage = v;
    }
    ...
}
...
```

It worth noting that this `Holder` interface would be something that you have created, implementing the methods `showTime` and `hideTime`. *This is not Android built-in*.

Comment: hideTime() is giving exception, do i need to call something else or its bydefault method ?

Comment: This is an example, you must implement an interface like that or call your own method to hide and show the components.

Comment: You could replace `showTime` and `hideTime` directly with the code to show and hide the components.